# Can't move variables outside of a function

Tags: actionscript-3

```
function playvideo(path:String, wid:Number=1280, heigt:Number=720):void
{
    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);
    var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.client = this;
    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusChanged);
    ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    var vid:Video = new Video(); 
    ns.play(path);
    vid.width = wid;
    vid.height = heigt;
    vid.attachNetStream(ns);
    mc_bg.removeChildAt(0);
    mc_bg.addChild(vid);
}
```

Greetings, here's my "playvideo" function. whenever I try to move variables outside of function to control the video from elsewhere(for example "vid"), specific movieclips and buttons dissapear(are not shown on the stage). Is that some kind of a bug or am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: The term you need to understand is "scope". Variables and functions only are accessible inside the brackets in which they are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this:

```
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
function playvideo(path:String, wid:Number=1280, heigt:Number=720):void
{
    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);
    var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.client = this;
    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, statusChanged);
    ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler);
    SoundMixer.stopAll();

    ns.play(path);
    vid.width = wid;
    vid.height = heigt;
    vid.attachNetStream(ns);
    mc_bg.removeChildAt(0);
    mc_bg.addChild(vid);
}
```

And same for any var, declare outside function

Comment: I guess you didn't understand my question:
A racing game which I'm creating has a video background shown by that function. When I put that variable inside the function, the movieclip that shows how much money you get after the race works, but when I put variable outside that function like you did, that movieclip disappears. Do I need to clear that variable or something like that? Thanks!

Comment: are you working with classes?, is AS3?, havse you tried to debug var when you called your function?

Comment: Yes, it's AS3, but I'm not working with any classes, just with a script in one frame. Are they neccessary? Tried to trace var, it just gives me "[object Video]".

Comment: then you got the variable outside function, not?

Comment: No, because if I move it to outside of function next frame's movieclips are not shown, just black screen.

Comment: put a stop(), put var into root?, make a movieclip with one frame and put inside, .... there is a lot of solutions under flash( ohh what a pretty remember of time ago)

Comment: Thanks, I've found a few work arounds that uses more memory, I guess there's no other way. I think I've made a mistake somewhere in my code which causes that movieclip to argue with that video. Thanks for your help, I appreciate that.